# Why would a creature evolve to see everything in inverted colours?

Tags: science-based, biology, evolution

I'm designing a creature that sees the world with inverted colours. I'm not sure whether to make it so the brain merely interprets colours as inverted, or the photopigments in their photoreceptors are full strength 24/7. Not too important anyways. The real question I'm asking is:

Why would such a creature evolve to see colours this way? What are some advantages and possible disadvantages to this adaptation?

Comment: What do you mean by "inverted"? What would be the normal, the non-inverted?

Comment: What we see as 'green' would be interpreted for them as red.

Comment: I'm not even sure that we both see the same green...

Comment: If you mix red and green paints you get grey. If you add red and green light you get yellow. There is not a univoque definition of "opposite color"

Comment: Color is a sensation. It exists in the mind. It is not a physical quantity; it does not exist in nature. *It is meaningless to speak of how a non-human creature perceives colors*, because color is a sensation which *exists only in the mind.*

Comment: @AlexP: The term ‘qualia’ is a sadly underused one.

Comment: @JoeBloggs: Well, in this specific case, color is a sensation which is pretty much the same for most humans. After all, we *have* been able to define colorspaces based on the sensations of a "standard observer", which, although not identical to any specific observer's sensations, are nevertheless close enough for photographic work. We have even been able to construct empirical formulas which enable us to predict what color the average human would perceive given a certain spectral composition of light in simple situations (but not in general -- color perception is *complicated*).

Comment: @Alexp: The ‘gold or blue dress’ is a good example of the generalisations breaking down with specific people. Brains are fun!

Comment: I don't get people hating on this question. It could have used a little more research, maybe, but look at all the discussion it sparked. If every question was downvoted like this, we'd have some pretty hard voting.

Answer (score 13):

**It won't make a difference**

Technically we see the whole world inverted and upside down. The light that reaches our retinas is mirrored and upside down when entering the eye. Our brain won't use the energy to flip it again inside our head. The brain just starts associating. Touching something on a certain spot goes with a visual and proprioception stimuli. Then we associate it with that spot. No flipping required.

There was a guy who started wearing glasses to invert and mirror the image. At first the brain is confused, but after some time (a month or so if I recall correctly) the brain had redone the association. The world was still very much flipped, but for him that was now his "normal" association. After three months he could even drive a car without problems. When he removed the glasses, it was now "inverted", even though the visual for him was now right side up again.

Same with colours. The stimulus is just associated with a colour. It could be we all see it differently, but our associations are the same. So if we both see a green colour, but in your head it is the reverse of mine, we still associate green. It doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4):

**It depends what precisely you mean by inverted.**

As others have said no-one knows how another person perceives "red".  We know that colour-blind people see colours differently from those who are not colour-blind. But we know this without knowing what "red" looks like to them, but by the fact that they can't distinguish between certain colours that others can.

Bees can see colours that humans cannot. Where we and they do see the same colours, they probably see them at different intensities from us.

If by inverted, you are referring to seeing differences in intensity of the each colour then that is certainly possible and does in fact happen.

**Why would such a creature evolve to see colours this way? What are some advantages and possible disadvantages to this adaptation?**

I suggest you study vision in insects and birds.

Some birds that appear black to us, have bright colours as seen by another bird.

[image]
https://www.blogarama.com/pets-blogs/279913-official-blog-vetdepotcom/8571129-what-colors-can-pets-actually-see

Bees can see colours in the ultraviolet that humans can't see. This means that flowers look very different to bees than to us.

**Your creature will see best in the areas of the spectrum that are most important to it**

This will depend on many things but mostly to the food it eats. Humans have good colour vision because apes in general have to distinguish between ripe and unripe fruits.  If your creature is an insectivore and eats only moths then it will be good at distinguishing drab moths from their background. It probably doesn't need many colours. If it eats butterflies then it needs to see bright colours and distinguish between poisonous and non-poisonous varieties. Another consideration especially in birds is the choice of a mate.

**Note**

I have made many statements from my general knowledge of biology. I haven't cited any sources at this point.  Strictly under the `science-based` tag I don't have to but I'll try to return later with links to the various facts.

---

[**photography of the invisible world**](http://photographyoftheinvisibleworld.blogspot.com/2015_06_07_archive.html)

[image]

Comment: Probably the best answer so far. It looks like he's searching for a different experience in his creatures, which you're giving him.

Answer (score 1):

There’s no difference.

A common question when people start to really think about identity is ‘What if the green I see isn’t the same as the green you see?’. Now, I can’t climb inside your brain and experience green through your eyes, so instead we settle for using a common vocabulary to describe shared (but subjectively experienced) phenomena. The technical term for such things is ‘qualia’.

Now, your species has a different physiological response to certain wavelengths and intensities of light. So do humans! Sometimes this alters the experience of the colours (For a fun example of that try googling ‘gold or blue dress’) but the majority of the time it doesn’t. Regardless of how you see green (or what your species sees as green) we will all use the same word to describe the same experiences. If you really want to blow your mind try look up imaginary and Stygian colours. Purple is an imaginary colour (there is no such thing as the purple wavelength, your brain just fills it in), and Stygian Blue is the colour you see if you stare at something yellow for too long. They’re colours that only exist in our heads, yet somehow we can all agree that purple is a colour.

Now, if your species were capable of seeing different colours (mantis shrimp, for example, can see all sorts of extra wavelengths) we’d have to agree on different words, but if they just see the ‘opposites’ (and defining opposite is a hard thing to do!) then their experience of the world and the way they would describe it to us would be no different.

After all, they have no proof that the red they see is the same as the green we see.

Comment: There is an interesting podcast about language and color (I don't have the original  reference, hope this one works) that suggests that before people (in this case, the Greeks) had a word for blue, they saw it as grey, shades of green, etc. https://www.theguardian.com/books/2010/jun/12/language-glass-colour-guy-deutscher#:~:text=It%20turned%20out%20that%20it,for%20black%20or%20for%20green.

Comment: @DWKraus: It's much more complicated than that; see the Kiwi Hellenist's discussion of colors in Homer ([part 1](https://kiwihellenist.blogspot.com/2016/01/colours-in-homer-1-bronze-sky.html), [part2](https://kiwihellenist.blogspot.com/2016/01/colours-in-homer-2-wine-dark-sea.html)). (And Ancient Greek never got a word meaning "blue in general"; Modern Greek has *μπλε* (ble), which is obviously a Germanic loanword.)

Answer (score 1):

## Light

Is a wave.

This wave is a composition of pure frequencies, with their intensities varying over time.

- Black (as commonly agreed) is an amplitude of zero across the visible frequencies.
- White (as commonly agreed) is an steady amplitude across the visible frequencies, usually quite high, otherwise its perceived as grey.

Red, green, Blue, or any other hue, shade, pigment of colour is some mix of these.

Humans (generally speaking) have 4 pigments in our retinal receptors.

Three of these are attuned to specific wavelengths nominally called: red, green, and blue.

The fourth is attuned to a broad spectrum of frequencies, but is quiet sensitive to amplitude. So much so that scientific studies have shown that people can detect single photons of light.

Some creatures are sensitive to higher frequencies of light (ultraviolet) like birds and bees. Some creatures are sensitive to lower frequencies of light (infrared) like snakes.

But light itself does not change based on the creature itself.

## Perception

It is possible for a human to see higher and lower frequency light. Its called a camera. Grab your tv remote face it at your phone camera and take a pic while your holding down the power on button. Your phone will show light, where you don't see any.

Similarly no two humans necessarily perceive light the same way. Case in point Blue/Green colour blind, and fully colour blind people can be that way because of missing pigments in their eyes, but they might also be that way because their brains aren't weird to make the distinction.

Your creature wouldn't necessarily see red as green. They are different wavelengths, but they might not be able to tell the difference between the two. Which can make for some very interesting art.

## Interesting Vision Change

If you really want to change how your creature perceives light, make them sensitive to light polarisation. This is the property of light that makes sun glasses work for us mere humans, as the glass blocks some percentage of the spinning light.

Sunglasses to such a creature would be like us putting on red filtered glasses, only being able to perceive just the red light, and not the other frequencies.

This could give the creature both an edge. They can see patterns that other creatures cannot. But it would also be a challenge, particularly around creatures without that vision as trying to understand their patterns would be hard. Red of one shade to a human is a flat colour, but to this creature might resemble a cubist impressionist piece done in many twists of red.

Comment: Bees can see polarized light https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn20058-bees-follow-polarised-light-through-a-maze/

Comment: Good answer. Better if you get a chance to add some citations, but very solid.

Comment: That "light spin" (which is meaningless) should be "[polarization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_(waves)) of light", or what? (Photon have spin 1, and only 1.)

Answer (score 1):

Color is a sensation. It exists in the mind. It is not a physical quantity; it does not exist in nature. *It is meaningless to speak of how a non-human creature perceives colors*, because color is a sensation which *exists only in the mind.*

(Yes, color is somehow associated with the spectral composition of light. In simple situations, that is, for objects covering a significant fraction of the visual field, the relationship is sufficiently straightforward so that we can define color spaces based on the sensations perceived by a "standard observer". Unfortunately, for small objects, that is, objects covering small fractions of the visual field, human color perception becomes irreducible to simple formulas.)

The question is simply about translation from the language of the alien creatures into English. They distinguish between what English calls "red" and what English calls "green"? Fine then, the word which they associate with what English calls "red" should be translated as "red", and the word associated with what English calls "green" should be translated as "green". *There is no way of telling what are the actual sensations in their mind.*

But what is even more interesting is that even *here on Earth* various languages do not agree on how to divide the color spectrum.

Examples from languages spoken here on Earth, concentrating on what the English language calls "blue":

- There is no Latin word which means plain "blue":

  - [*caeruleus*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcaeruleus1) could mean "dark blue", or it could mean "azure", or (quite often) it could mean "dark colored" (as opposite to *albus*), or (etymologically) it could mean "sky blue". (This is the word which Tacitus uses to describe the "blue eyes" of the Germans.)
  - [*venetus*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/venetus) means "blue-green", like the sea, "marine blue". (Fun factoid: the names of the famous combative factions of the Constantinopolitan hippodrome which fired up spectacularly in the [Nika riots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nika_riots) are usually translated as "the Greens" and "the Blues", but they were actually "*factio prasina*" (leek-green) and "*factio veneta*" (marine blue).
  - [*lividus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dlividus) means "lead blue" like the sky when covered with clouds.

  The point being that one cannot translate English "blue" into Latin without knowing the context; there is no Latin word which would always fit. This is so vexing that in Medieval Latin they began using a new word, *blavus* (on the model of English "blue", German "blau", French "bleu"), specifically in order to translate the word "blue".
- And what about Greek, where *glaukos* (blue-green) and *kharopos* (blue-gray) are considered two of the four basic eye colors? (The other two are *melanos*, black, and *aigôpos*, brown.) (Ancient Greeks perceived the Germans as having *kharopa ommata*, "blue-gray eyes"; compare the *caerulei oculi* of Tacitus above.) Notably, for the the Ancient Greeks there were no "green" eyes.
- Famously, the Russian language considers that *siniy* (dark blue) and *goluboy* (sky blue) are completely different colors; they are as different as yellow and green. One cannot translate the English phrase "blue car" into Russian without known what kind of blue it is.

Answer (score 0):

#### How do you invert colours?

I don't ask this provoke conflict or anything, this isn't a misposted clarification question, serious thought needs to be put into what colour your animal could originally see, and then how it's inverted.

Colour is an extremely complex thing. Take this diagram:
[image]

The main shape is what the human eye can see. The circumference is single wavelength light (pure electromagnetic waves). The triangle is a representation of what your computer can represent. The curved line going into the centre is what colour you get when you heat something up.

#### So - how you do you "invert"?

A typical algorithm (with 8 bit RGB) is to subtract all 3 values from 255. So, for a point in that triangle, measure the distance to all 3 points on a scale such that 255 is on the point, and 0 is on the far edge, and subtract those values from 255. (Green becomes purple, Blue becomes yellow, Red becomes Cyan etc).

However that triangle is arbitrary, we could put it anywhere! The "Primary colours" we named after those points are arbitrary choices based on what is easy to display on a screen.

But what do we do with 1000K Red? it's outside the triangle. This means it's "more red" than than red we've defined as a primary colour.

Inversion is more complex in 4 or more colour systems, eg bird, fish, amphibian, reptile, insect, some mammals, and the odd lucky human. However you may invert by flipping the hue, or converting to HSV and flipping the brightness channel. You can also invert in some colour systems a colour which your eye could see and then be unable to see it, or invert in ways which would require a negative contribution from certain frequencies:
[image]

Inverting is just a transform within this colour diagram; I have a "Dark mode" plugin for my browser which inverts bright webpages, there are something like 30 different behaviour choices.

So if your transform just works within that triangle (like an sRGB inversion), nothing will change - you learn Red as 460nm and blue as 620nm and that's how it always has been. But if you carefully define your inversion within a colour system you specially craft you can improve the vision, allowing your eyes to make out new colours you couldn't previously see.

Here's what a finch can see as a function of the receptors in its eye:
[image]

By carefully moving these ranges, or tweaking the fadeoff for an individual receptor, you could change the range your creature can make out.